# Installation via android studio works but manual apk installation doesn't

Tags: java, android, apk

i have a problem with installing my app via APK.
The app works fine on multiple devices when i install it with Android studio,
or when i run it via emulator, but when i generate APK file, put it in my phone
and try to manually install it, main activity gets opened and when i click any 
button it just crashes.

Comment: Use LogCat to examine the Java stack trace associated with the crash.

Comment: It would be difficult for anyone to help you without seeing that stack trace. See [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23353173/2745495).

Comment: How do you generate APK file?

Comment: Disable instant Run then Build -> Make Project. You will able to install the apk after it.